# What component can this be?

Tags: components, identification

(this is the last of my unknown components).

It is less than 1 cm (half inch) diameter, has one wire on each end.

It has description:

CNR C8G 75L RU G12

The RU is written reversed.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a spark gap to me.

Comment: Thanks ... I think this components comes from an old Philips CRT

Comment: might be a varistor. Check where it came from – if it's from a degaussing coil circuit, almost certainly a varistor.

Comment: Looks like a 75 volt gas discharge tube.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### It's a GDT

What you're looking at is almost certainly a Gas Discharge Tube, or GDT for short.  They are basically a spark gap inside a sealed chamber filled with a specific inert gas mixture -- this allows them to provide more precise protection than an air spark gap.  They're used for the same things as spark gaps, though -- mostly, overvoltage protection as when they break over and start conducting, they will "crowbar" the overvoltage.

Comment: It is, definitely. CNR makes GDTs, and the PDF I just found (but couldn't copy the link on this tablet) shows TV applications. If it's 75 volts, it may be slightly radioactive.

Comment: [Here is the link](http://www.turus.com.tr/class/INNOVAEditor/assets/PDF/gasdischarge.pdf).